# How to add a custom html template to asp.net identity?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, templates, asp.net-identity

I'm kinda stuck at this point - I want to add a custom html email template to my registration in asp.net identity, i.e when the user gets a link to register then it should have some sort of a format/ template.

```
 if (result.Succeeded) {
     var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
     var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new {
         userId = user.Id, code = code
     }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
     await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
     ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
     return View("DisplayEmail");
 }
```

In the above code, a link is sent to the user. I want to send it in a format, with a header, footer and the body should have the link. So my understanding is that I need to put in a template. How can that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your confirmation/invitation method you can use something like this to send a personalized email confirmation/invitation :

```
    public ActionResult Your_Method()
    {
        //... your auth login  .... 

        //Load email setting from config
        var EmailFrom = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"];
        var EmailTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailTo"];
        var EmailSubject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSubject"];

        var currentUser = //your current user data for example from session or from the code/database;
        try
        {
                if (currentUser != null)
                {
                    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                    {
                        using (var message = new MailMessage())
                        {
                            var from = new MailAddress(EmailFrom);
                            var to = new MailAddress(EmailTo);

                            message.To.Add(to);
                            message.From = from;
                            message.Subject = EmailSubject;
                            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                            message.Body = $@"
    Dear user: {currentUser.FName ?? string.Empty} {currentUser.LName ?? string.Empty}  <br/>
    Welcome to our website! Your id: {currentUser.Id ?? string.Empty} <br/>
    Other information: {currentUser.information ?? string.Empty} <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Contact Us Email : {"website@website.ru"}<br/>
    Contact Us Phone : {"+7 913 123 4567"} <br/>
    ";
                            smtp.Send(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log your exception somethere
            //e.HandleException(LogLevel.Fatal);
        }

        //And then you can return some JSON 
        var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_return_object);
        return new ContentResult {Content = response, ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8, ContentType = "application/json"};

        //Or show a View or redirect 
        return View();

        //Or show nothing 
        return return new EmptyResult();

        //It depends on your logic 
    }
```

You would also need to include

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <!-- Email configuration -->
      <add key="EmailFrom" value="email@email.net" />
      <add key="EmailTo" value="yourcustomer@email.net" />
      <add key="EmailSubject" value="subject of your email" />
   </appSettings>
   <system.net>
      <!-- SMTP configuration -->
      <mailSettings>
         <smtp>
            <network host="MAIL_SERVER" port="25" userName="USER_NAME" password="USER_PASSWORD" />
         </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
   </system.net>
   ...
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE:**
Question has been updated, so here is a little bit more information:
According the the MSDN [UserManager.SendEmailAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497571(v=vs.108).aspx)

the method's syntax is

```
public virtual Task SendEmailAsync(
    TKey userId,
    string subject,
    string body
)
```

so it is even more simple for you. You can customize a "body" of the email doing something like that:

```
var header = "Dear user: <br/>";
var footer = "Thank you <br/> website.com";
var originalBody = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>"

var newEmailBody =  header+"<br/>"+originalBody+"<br/>"+footer;
await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", newEmailBody);
```

I would encourage you to use C# 6.0 for String Interpolation you can read more about it here [How C# 6.0 Simplifies, Clarifies and Condenses Your Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879355.aspx)

Keep in mind that the body of the email is html, so you can make it pretty and format as you want.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. I edited my question, can you please help me out with that?